# Запись нового файла

Tags: python, csv

Сильно я туплю и не могу могу объединить два файла так, чтобы в финальный файл funnel.csv записывались не все строки из visit_log.csv. А только те, чьи пользователи совершали покупки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо делать?
Само задание: Для каждого user_id в файле visit_log.csv определите третий столбец с категорией покупки (если покупка была, сам файл visit_log.csv изменять не надо). Запишите в файл funnel.csv визиты из файла visit_log.csv, в которых были покупки с указанием категории.
Учтите условия на данные:
содержимое purchase_log.txt помещается в оперативную память компьютера
содержимое visit_log.csv - нет; используйте только построчную обработку этого файла. Код ниже

```
with open('visit_log.csv', 'r') as f, open('funnel.csv', 'w') as f2:
    for row in f:
        line_list=row.strip().split(',')
        if line_list[0] in new_dict.keys():
            line_list.append(new_dict[line_list[0]])
            add_line=','.join(line_list)
        elif line_list[0]=='user_id':
            line_list.append('category')
            add_line=','.join(line_list)
        else:
            add_line=','.join(line_list)
        f2.write(add_line+'\n')
    import csv

    with open('funnel.csv', newline='') as File:  
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
*['d1a2f22f01', 'other']*
*['c6bd818cce', 'email']*
*['c4f230c2a5', 'None']*
**['463ba5e7a4', 'context', 'Бытовая техника']**
*['46ca7872b5', 'other']*
*['8bad7f963f', 'context']*
 .........
 .........
 .........
```

вот нужны в ответе только строки с типом покупки

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

final_dict = {} 

with open('purchase_log.txt') as purchases: 
  for i, line in enumerate(purchases): 


    dict_ = json.loads(line) 

    key = dict_['user_id']
    value = dict_['category']

    final_dict[key] = value


with open('visit_log.csv', 'r') as f, open('funnel.csv','w') as f_2:
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    if line[0] in final_dict.keys():
      line.append(final_dict[line[0]])
      ad_line = ','.join(line)

      f_2.write(ad_line + '\n')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]